# How do i get the right return type from a template function?

Tags: c++

I am looking into template functions right now and found a question i have no answer for. Lets say i have a max function that compares two numbers and returns the bigger number. It should be possible to compare different types(int with double, double with int etc.). The function looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename A>
A max(T a, A b) {
    return (a>b) ? a: b;
}
```

Now when i call the function with max(2.5,1) it returns 2, since A is the return type and the double will be an int. If i change the return type to T, and call the function again it will return 2.5 which is what i want, but if i call max(1,2.5) it will return 2 again, but i want 2.5. Is there a way to always return the type of the bigger number, no matter the return type and the order of the numbers i typed in?

I tried different combinations, but couldnt figure out how to get my desired return type.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Note, though, that if we take the question *literally*, *"Is there a way to always return the type of the bigger number"*, then `max(1.5, 2)` should return an `int`.

Comment: @Bob__ oh didnt read carefully enough. @ OP please unaccept my answer. It is not right

Comment: I will delete my answer for now until I have time to fix it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I actually think that the OP should clarify if they *really* want that or what your answer is suggesting (which is IMHO much more useful).

Comment: @Bob__ what i wanted is what i got when i put auto as return type like 463035818_is_not_a_number suggested. If i call max(1.5,2) with auto as return type returns 2, which is exactly what i want.

Comment: @Bob__ well yeah, at least the answer should explain why what OP is asking for is not what they really want ;)

Comment: @eraser No, with `auto` it returns the common type, not the type of the bigger value. Check with `cout << typeid(max(1.5,2).name();`. https://godbolt.org/z/7bG7es1YE

Comment: @mch ok now i understand what you guys mean. I didnt express myself correctly. I wanted to return the bigger number in its own type and NOT return the type of the bigger number. Therefore auto works perfectly fine for me. I hope this clarifies what i want.

Comment: @eraser Thanks for replying. I still think there's still a bit of a misunderstanding, probably I'm too nitpicking and I didn't express my point clearly enough. *"I wanted to return the bigger number in its own type"* to me, it means that `max(1.5, 2)` should return a variable of **type** `int` and **value** 2. Using `common_type`, you'll have one of **type** `double` and **value** 2.0. I believe the latter is a more common expectation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, what you ask for literally does not make much sense because C++ is statically typed. Consider this:

```
int a = 0;
double b = 0.0;
std::cin >> a >> b;
?? x = max(a,b);
```

What type is `x`? You need to pick. At compile time. Hence you cannot return the type of the bigger of `a` and `b`. `auto x` does not help, because `auto` merely makes the compiler pick but it is not known wich is bigger before the user entered the numbers. What you can choose as return type is the common type of `a` and `b`.

You can use [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T, typename A>
std::common_type_t<T,A> max(T a, A b) {
    return (a>b) ? a: b;
}
```

Though anyhow the conditional operator has that type so you can simply use `auto`:

```
template <typename T, typename A>
auto max(T a, A b) {
    return (a>b) ? a: b;
}
```

Note that this will not auto-magically adjust the return type to either `T` or `A` depending on which value is bigger. It will return the type of the conditional operator and is effectively the same as the code with the `std::common_type`.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rq1dTWEP9)

On the other hand, if `a` and `b` are known at compile time, then you can determine the type of the bigger value and use it:

```
template <auto a,auto b>
auto max() {
    if constexpr(a > b) return a;
    else return b;
}

int main() {    
    std::cout << max<1,2.5>();  // double non type template argument since c++20
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1MMnfesjf)

Comment: You could technically return an `std::variant` or an `std::any`, though I'm not sure it makes sense to in this case.

Comment: @Hasturkun technically yes. It just defers the issue to the caller though